# Prove that there is an interval $[a, b] ⊆ I$ such that $f$ coincides with a polynomial there.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f ∈ C^{\infty}$ satisfy the following property: To each $x ∈ I=[0,1]$ there corresponds a finite integer $N_x$ such that $f^n(x) = 0 $for all $n ≥ N_x.$ Prove that there is an interval $[a, b] ⊆ I$ such that $f$ coincides with a polynomial there.

My Try:

I tried to use Rolle's Theorem but failed since it gives information only on derivatives of $f$. I couldn't even start the proof. Can somebody please help me? at least a hint?

Comment: Have you learned Taylor's expansion?

Comment: @FrankLu Oh this makes sense now. So for a fixed point $x_0\in (0,1)$ I can write the Taylor series of $f$ since $f\in C^{\infty}$ and after a particular term it has $0$. then I have a polynomial and this polynomial is valid for a nbhd of $x_0$. Am I correct?  thanks!

Comment: I like this variant: suppose every $x\in[0,1]$ is contained in an interval $(a,b)$ on which $f$ coincides with a polynomial. (Also at the endpoints: there are such intervals of the form $[0,b)$ and $(a,1]$.) Prove that $f$ is actually a polynomial on all of $[0,1]$.